# Can the synchronous Larmor precession of several nuclei cause the emergence of a quasiparticle system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, material-science

As phonon's form due to the synchronous oscillation of their vibrational modes, couldn't the same apply to the synchronous oscillation of a system of protons oscillating at their fundamental frequency?

Comment: I searched and cannot find a system just consisting of just protiums.  Precession against what magnetic field?

Comment: Protium is just a system of normal hydrogen, without any heavier isotopes, like deuterium and tritium.

Comment: The magnetic field strength does not matter to the physics of the question, just the feasibility of it. At any magnetic field strengths, a proton will have a Larmer precession. The stronger the field, the higher the frequency, but there is always a oscillatory mode at any given strength.

Comment: but your question is about  bulk property, phonons are a useful model in bulk matter. I have not found bulk protiums alone, but with deuterium or in water.. Do you have a link?

Comment: Can be any system containing Hydrogen H1. There are only specific isotopes that have a Larmor precession. Water works. I do not think there should be a strong focus on this, more on the  quantization of the system due to this.

Comment: Phonos appear because  of the coherent  rotational and vibrational levels of the molecules,in water for example. Nothing external to the fluid.  How do you envisage a coherent behavior of the precession?  in an imposed magnetic field?

Comment: As you have mentioned, phonon's form from the coherent rotational and vibrational level of molecules. With Larmor Precession, as is used in NMR, at a given magnetic strength, certain nucleus (Proton in the case of H1) will oscillate to the frequency of a certain electromagnetic wave.

Comment: I would like to that in the case of phonon's, be it in water or any other medium, there has to be a interaction within the material that causes this collective excitation. Same with any quasiparticle. The question is if a quasiparticle, ideally with an integer spin, can be formed by the coherent oscillation of protium, or for that matter, any nucleus that can be influenced by Larmor procession.

Comment: well, it needs an expert  in phonons to answer this, My intuitive reaction is "not if there is not external magnetic field" . If there is a field it might just change the "definition" of phonons. This for example " https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02735509.pdf "

Answer (score 1):

Quasiparticles are an inherently many-body effect. For this reason Larmor procession, which is a single particle effect, cannot lead to quasiparticles. It is not enough to have a bunch of oscillators side by side that happen to be in sync with each other, you need those oscillators to be *interacting*.

If you did manage to set up a bunch of protons with interacting spins, the quasiparticle that may emerge would be a [magnon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnon); a particle of magnetic excitation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I overlooked the many-body effect importance. Knowledge acquired.